# Selenium Webdriver unable to change window size in Windows Server 2012 EC2 instance

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver, windows-server-2012

Our Selenium WebDriver tests are run remotely in TeamCity on a Windows server 2012 EC2 instance.

I am unable to resize the browser when using chrome on this instance. It works fine with Firefox, but chrome is stuck in 1024 X 768.

I have tried the following methods to resize, but none have worked.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("--start-maximized")

WebDriver.Current.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width, height);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1080");
```

all methods work locally on windows 10, with chrome version 49.0.2623.110 and chrome driver version 2.9 on both machines.

Is there any way to resize the chrome browser I haven't tried, or is this a chromedriver issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));
```

Answer (score 0):

**By default** maximum size of our chrome window is **(1040, 784)**. setting windows size **will not work directly**. instead you need to do Following actions,

1. we need to **increase the Virtual memory** of the EC2 instance.
2. or open your chrome in **headless mode** and **then set your screen size** in your chrome option.

same issue happened for me. I resolved by 2nd option because **increasing instance will increase the cost**.